# Send data from FIFO memory module to USB

Tags: usb, fifo

I have a FIFO module running at 24MHz, producing 1 byte per clock. Then it produces 24MB/s. I need to send this data to PC through USB or Ethernet.

How can I achieve this?
Doesn't exist some USB controller or something?
Searching in the web I read about I2C but it seems very slow for my purposes.

This is what I'd like. However I'm able to reduce the amount of data to 6MB/s if no solution exists for the previous requirement.

Comment: 24MB/s is a fairly high datarate. Your average consumer grade USB2 external disk does around 20MB/s.

Comment: I don't need to save it on hard disk. I only need to process data. However I'm able to reduce the amount of data, even below 6MB/s. What is the highest speed I can reach?

Comment: Just try to give an indication of how much data you are trying to send into the PC.

Comment: The indication is 6MB/s. Below I sacrifice too much quality. However I just found this one http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/DataSheets/ICs/DS_FT245R.pdf
It says "full speed USB 2.0". Do you think it could be what I'm looking for?

Comment: Full speed USB2.0 is just the name of the protocol used, it tells you little to nothing about the actual datarate. You have to check the datasheet for that.

Comment: The datasheet says "USB 2.0 Full Speed compatible", so I assume the speed is  12 Mbit/s

Comment: Bad assumption. Also 12Mb/s is something different than 12MB/s, it differs an order of magnitude (bit vs. byte).

Comment: "12Mb/s is something different than 12MB/s". I never asserted they're equal.

Comment: You mentioned 24 and 6 MByte/second in your question and some comments. How does that relate to 12Mbit/s? (which is still only the name of the protocol, the actual achievable datarate is lower). Check into chat if you want to discuss this further: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering

Comment: Check the FT245 chip and google for the maximum data rates people have achieved with it.

Comment: I read 1200 Mbit/s. This is not enaugh for me. I have an Arduino 2009. What about reading a byte from inputs, store the byte in a buffer (64? 512? more?) and then send the buffer via USB? The clock is 16MHz so I would expect a speed of 16MB/s. Am I right?

Comment: If you MB means MegaBit your are only neglecting all overhead. As a first guess count on 100% overhead. If you MB means MegaByte there is further factor of 8.

Comment: B is Byte, b is bit. However.. What overhead should I count? I read 8 bit in 8 different inputs and in the same cycle I store them in the buffer. When it's full I flush it. Even in case of 100% overhead I cannot understand why should I divide by 8. Can you explain please?

Comment: The software radio people with fairly similar needs manage to fill up USB2 pipes to a high degree using things like the Cypress FX2 parts - and presumably today the FX3.